# How to make own content more canonical than existing content on meetup.com?

Tags: google, canonical-url

I want to abandon meetup.com and provide all of our event data on another server, to own our content. As I have no control over the meetup server apart from the settings they offer me as a group host, **how can I convince Google that our own server is more canonical than meetup.com?**

What I already tried: editing group descriptions, adding links to resources outside of meetup.com. Refraining from linking to meetup.com when posting an event on LinkedIn or other social media.

I do not have any code examples to offer.

Comment: Meetup has a lot of reputation, it probably isn't possible to post the same information they have and get Google to choose your page as the canonical.